# multi value attribute in primary key rdbms

Tags: mysql, database-design, rdbms

I am creating a new database design in which i got stuck in a problem. I am having a table with attribute(A,B,C,D,E) here (A,B,C,D) is composite key which uniquely define E . My problem is attribute D is multi valued Which is a part of primary key.Currently i am thinking using comma separated values for D but it also has some limitations as while searching for E the values in D should be in same order as they were inserted.As-

> Let D is i,j,k So My Table T is A,B,C,D(i,j,k)->E
>
> > Now if i want the result then i should fire query in same order as (A,B,C,D(i,j,k)).

So i am wondering is there any other better way to do this thing.

Comment: Did you mean "which uniquely determine E"?

Comment: yes. complete combination of A,B,C,D can only determine E

Answer (score 1):

Don't use comma separated values as one of the fields in a composite primary key.  When you do this, you are really creating a table that is not in First Normal Form, even though it may appear to be 1NF to the DBMS.

First Normal Form was devised way back when the relational model was brand new.  It's purpose was to guarantee keyed access to all data.  Don't define your keys in a way that defeats the purpose of having keys.

Here's what to do:  First decompose the rows of your table into separate rows for each individual value in D, so that D doesn't have to be a multivalue any more.  This will conform to 1NF, but will probably be in violation of 2NF, since non key values may be determined by just A, B, and C.  You will probably want to decompose into two tables so as to conform to 2NF.  And you may want to normalize even more than that.